# asp.net mvc displaying dropdown value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a dropdownlist by fetching data from database.I want to display the selected value on click of submit. In controller I am trying to store the selected value in `ViewBag` and display it. When I debugged the code, I came to know that viewbag stores `null` value.The following line stores the value in viewbag.

```
ViewBag.scode = emp.Service_Code;
```

While debugging, `Service_Code` shows the value but it gets stored as `null` in `ViewBag`. Please help me in solving this issue.

**Model**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Service_Code { get; set; }
    public string Service_Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  ser_code { get; set; } 
}
```

**View**

```
@model mvclearn.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "menu";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("save", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Service_Code, Model.ser_code, "--select-",new { @class = "form-control" })
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-block" />
    }
 </div>
 <div>You entered:@ViewBag.scode</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult menu()
{
    RevenueDashboardEntities rdb = new RevenueDashboardEntities(); 
    var model = new Employee()
    {
        ser_code = new SelectList(db.Services, "Service_Code", "Service_Name")    
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(Employee emp)
{
    RevenueDashboardEntities rdb = new RevenueDashboardEntities();
    ViewBag.scode = emp.Service_Code;
    return View("menu");   
}
```

Comment: Your code would be throwing [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected value is already getting post in the action via model in `Service_Code` property of it.

What you need here is return your model back to view and it will populate the selected value with what was selected at form post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(Employee emp)
{
    RevenueDashboardEntities rdb = new RevenueDashboardEntities();
    // this is needed to populate the items of dropdown list again
    emp.ser_code  = new SelectList(db.Services, "Service_Code", "Service_Name");
    // sending model back to view
    return View("menu",emp);   
}
```

Now the value will be auto selected on page load after form is posted and you can display the value on the page inside div by writing:

```
<div>You entered: @Model.Service_Code</div>
```

Comment: How to display that selected value in view?

Comment: `<div>You entered: @Model.Service_Code</div>`

Comment: Great @PriteshNaik please mark it as answer too then :)

Comment: Hello @EhsanSajjad,thanks for your help.One more doubt,how to get the selected dropdownlist value in my controller to perform some manipulation?

Comment: you are already having that in there in the property `emp.Service_Code`